# Mysterious variable in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking at some sql code with the following structure:

```
set @var =
(
    select count(1) from
    (
        select * from table where field = 1
    )
    someVariable
)
```

It won't seem to run unless "someVariable" is in the statement.  My question is, what does this "someVariable" represent, and why is it in the query?  I don't understand why I can't set @var to the select count statement outright, so the "someVariable" is really throwing me off.

Comment: RE: "I don't understand..." You can just use `SELECT @var =COUNT(*) from table where field = 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derived tables need to have aliases. `someVariable` is functioning as an alias in this case.

Comment: Ah I see. Based on the research I did just now, it looks like you can set it "AS" and then the derived table name. But it's working without the "AS" also. Does dat "AS" indicate anything?

Comment: I see, so it doesn't mean anything different if you have or don't have the "AS".  Ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When I run a similar query on MySQL, I got:

```
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

The inner select actually gives rise to a derived table, and someVariable is it's alias.

Comment: The question is about [tag:sql-server-2008] not MySQL

Comment: yes, but in this case it doesn't really matter. See the accepted answer  and the error message I've posted